# MVC C# pass information from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, tempdata

I have a problem, that I have a bit of trouble figuring out. I need to pass some data, a String, from a Controller to an already strongly typed view. 
I'm currently working in a live environment, sort of, so I don't completly know about the structure or what other Controllers/views are passed, except the ones I'm working in.

I'm guessing there's more than one, since a simple ViewBag doesn't seem to work. I've tried storing the string in the viewbag, but that didn't show up on the view. For clarification, I used:

```
Viewbag.PassedString = "This is a test"
```

.

```
<div> @Viewbag.PassedString </div>
```

Anyway, like I said that didn't work, I'm guessing the data was lost in the process. 
Next, I tried using TempData, but that doesn't work either atm.

Am I forgetting something important? Are there any alternatives to get the job done?

Comment: Hope your action has proper return statement. I think you better show your whole action and view codes here.

Comment: Yeah, the return statement is there. It's a return Json(...). I'm seeing in the comments that it doesn't actually 'return' any info, just to signify the method is done.

Comment: @I_Am_Not_user3185054: If your method returns JSON, it doesn't return a view. If it doesn't return a view, then a Viewbag has no use (as it is used exclusively while rendering the view). Your method does not return an actual page,.

Comment: @I_Am_Not_user3185054 The return should be like return view(); And the return type should be viewresult or actionresult.

Comment: Ah righto, that makes sense I guess. Thanks for the info. Do you happen to know about any alternatives, that I could use? I'm slightly hesitant to start changed the Model that is used, because this is a live environment and not somewhere I can screw around a bit.

Comment: Could you provide your full code of controller and use in view? Maybe create some example in dotnetfiddle?

Comment: I think you can see the code through this link. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DEDq4E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typo here..name of property should be same both side for example you have made "p" small in your view instead of that,

Try

```
<div> @Viewbag.PassedString </div>
```

**Update** :-

From your query I am understanding that you are returing json, ViewBag is used to pass data from the controller to the View Engine. in this case you are returning json, no view, so to make Viewbag work it should return a view.

**One more Update** :-

Well in your code I guess you can pass object here:-

write

```
 return Json(dataYouWantToPass, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of

```
return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in your jquery you can get as below in success call :-

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetDownloadLink", "Export"))",
                data: { "stadId": stadId, "catId": catId },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#bezig-tekst').html('');
                    $('#download-link').show();
                    alert(data); ////here you get the data you sent from controller.
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve xml.');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a quick example of mine. It's not the actual code I'm using. In my code I made sure to copy/paste the key, to make sure that didn't happen. Thanks anyway

Comment: so you mean to say in your code its still not working @I_Am_Not_user3185054?

Comment: Yes indeed. I used exactly what I did above. Viewbag.Keyword = "Data"     @Viewbag.Keyword. But that's not working. Did I forget anything regarding strongly/weakly typed data?

Comment: for that we need to see your whole code @I_Am_Not_user3185054

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but it's not working yet I'm afraid. I tried to changed it to a Return View, but nothing yet. The page gave an alert, he couldn't retrieve the XML. If I call the method that is used, there isn't actually returned a completly new view btw, a small part of the page is 'refreshed' or slightly changed. I only need to give that little bit of information towards the user.

Comment: cant you fill that particular information in json object which you are sending back? I guess viewbag is not correct option for your case @I_Am_Not_user3185054

Comment: I suppose that is possible yes, but how would I be able to store that information and retrieve it afterwards, if you don't mind me asking? 
Also I pasted my code in a .NET fiddle doc, I think you can see this. They're 3 files (MVC).

Comment: take a look here http://chsakell.com/2013/06/08/retrieve-json-data-from-mvc-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc/ specially "GetProductDataJson" method....you can pass object in return json as the first argument in your code which is "" I guess @I_Am_Not_user3185054

Comment: It worked! Thanks! It ended up being pretty much perfect. My supervisor corrected a bit of the code, I had pasted too much of it, but now it works about perfectly :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error (what are you use as editor?). You should use this in your controller:

```
ViewBag.PassedString = "This is a test";
```

and this in view:

```
@ViewBag.PassedString
```